# Border color like firebug inspect element

Tags: css

I would like to reproduce the border color made by firebug when you try to inspect the DOM element in a web page.

It looks like the border around the text "Link2" of the following image.

[image: enter link description here]

The border around the text "Link" is what I did. The code is visible from this link.
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f3gnq/2/).

Can someone help me to write the css code to reproduce the border of Link2?

Thanks

Comment: What problem are you having? Why not just take a screenshot of Firebug in action, use a paint program to find the relevant colours, and then use those?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to use box-shadows, like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/GolezTrol/AEDsY/

```
.cl3 {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px 3px lightblue;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 3px 3px lightblue;
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px 3px lightblue;
}
```

Comment: I think that the color `#55AAFF` looks better and it's closer to firebug's. +1 for me

Answer (score 2):

That effect is achieved using the [`box-shadow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/box-shadow) css property.

To get as much support as possible, use `-moz-box-shadow`, `-webkit-box-shadow` and `box-shadow`.

To get your desired effect, use:

```
 -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 2px blue;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 2px blue;
 box-shadow: 0 0 5px 2px blue;
```

Answer (score 2):

You would use something like this:

```
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px blue; /* Saf3-4 */
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px blue; /* FF3.5 - 3.6 */
box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px blue; /* Opera 10.5, IE9, FF4+, Chrome 10+ */
```

Check out http://css3please.com/ - it's a great resource for playing with new CSS properties.